help me with cron configuration
I can't get crontab to work. I entered these parameters from cpanel, where do I go wrong?
SHELL="/bin/bash"
*/5 * * * * * /usr/local/bin/php /home/myname/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/bin/cron.php

Does this method work for you? https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/setup/jobs/#wp-cli

What you have said you have done is not super clear, but I will assume you meant this to be two lines in a crontab file. I cannot speak to how you set that in cpanel, but I will address the crontab part.
You are setting the execution shell deliberately by setting SHELL to bash. This is probably fine, but you should omit the quotes. It's also probably not relevant as you are immediately calling php instead.
The second line (starting */5) has too many values in it. There should only be 5 before the command you want to execute.
Try this:
SHELL=/bin/bash 
*/5 * * * *  /usr/local/bin/php /home/myname/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/bin/cron.php

